# prove increasing of this inequality on this interval?

Tags: real-analysis, gamma-function, monotone-functions

I want to prove the following inequality for $x \in (0,1)$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\Gamma(x+1)>\frac{\frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100}}{\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1}\quad \tag{1}
\end{eqnarray*}

Let
\begin{align*}
f(x) &:=\log \left(\Gamma(x+1) \left(\frac{\pi^2 x}{9\gamma}+1\right) \right) \\
g(x) &:=\log \left( \frac{(900\gamma^2+73\pi^2)x}{900\gamma}+\frac{73}{100} \right).
\end{align*}

and define

\begin{eqnarray*}
w(x) := \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} ,
\end{eqnarray*}

For $x \in (0, 1)$ $g(x)>0$ holds, but $g$ and $f(x)$ are not equal to zero!
What it need to get it valid for this condition (theorem)?

Comment: Is $\gamma$ the Euler–Mascheroni constant? I don't really how it would help to show that $g'$ and $f'$ are zero, you want to show that $f(x) > g(x)$. Also could you give some more context for the problem?

Comment: Where does this come from?  Why are there three exact copies, [this](/questions/3238118) and [this](/questions/3245940), appearing in the last 7 days?

Comment: no i want to prove f\g >0 as i supposed ,but in generally i want to prove inequality (1) ,the Euler–Mascheroni  is constant